# copy unsorted cels to another spreadsheet from col to row, now stuck at array

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

im trying to copy from one sheet to another, will use that script on multiple sheets

i get that info (externaly using IMPORTHTML, dont control order) to a col in that order and want to rearange to a row in another order

i think i got source and target right and declared data i want to copy, but now i need to work with array  and that is beyound my current skills

```
function Export_Relacao()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

  var s_data = ss.getSheetByName('DATA');  // sheet where openById is stored
  var target_Id = s_data.getRange(2,26,1,1).getValues(); // DATA!Z2 = openById 

  var s_info = ss.getSheetByName('Info');  // Target sheet

  var A = s_info.getRange('C11').getValue();  // Ticket
  var B = s_info.getRange('C3').getValue();   // Codigo CVM
  var C = s_info.getRange('C4').getValue();   // CNPJ
  var D = s_info.getRange('C5').getValue();   // Empresa
  var E = s_info.getRange('C6').getValue();   // Razão Social
  var F = s_info.getRange('C13').getValue();  // Tipo de Ação
  var G = s_info.getRange('C9').getValue();   // Listagem
  var H = s_info.getRange('C10').getValue();  // Atividade
  var I = s_info.getRange('C18').getValue();  // Setor
  var J = s_info.getRange('C19').getValue();  // Subsetor
  var K = s_info.getRange('C20').getValue();  // Segmento
  var L = s_info.getRange('C7').getValue();   // Situação Registro


  var S_Info = s_info.getValues[[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L]];

  var ss_t = SpreadsheetApp.openById(target_Id);   // Target spreadsheet
  var t_relacao = ss_t.getSheetByName('Relação');  // Target sheet

  var lr = t_relacao.getLastRow();
  var lc = t_relacao.getLastColumn();

  var export_r = t_relacao.getRange(lr,1,1,1).getValues()
.appendRow.setValues(S_Info);


}
```

current code is giving me error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '[object Array]' of undefined
Export_Relacao  @ EXPORT.gs:24
```

couldnt find similar problem to try to adapt my script, any help to solve my problem and improve the code would be much appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately, from `i get that info (externaly using IMPORTHTML, dont control order) to a col in that order and want to rearange to a row in another order`, I cannot understand about your goal. I apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand about your goal, can you provide the sample input and output situation you expect?

Comment: i basicly just commented on that, could do individual  IMPORTHTML, but thats not the point, created a sheet just to showcasa and be easier to understand https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zSdRsU47DJYQkkm9PIH2y7wlhA8tzaJJ_ZrjfqckW4M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I notices that your issue has already been resolved. I'm glad for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You need to create an array with your values of interest, nest it into a second array and assign to a row with `setValues()`

- To create an array you can simply define `var myArray = []`
- To add values to an array, you can use the method [push()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)
- The method [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) expects a rectangular grid of values - that is a 2D array and is to be applied on a range of the same dimension (correct number of rows and columns) as the value range.

Sample:

```js
function Export_Relacao()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

  var s_data = ss.getSheetByName('DATA');  // sheet where openById is stored
  var target_Id = s_data.getRange(2,26,1,1).getValues(); // DATA!Z2 = openById 

  var s_info = ss.getSheetByName('Info');  // Target sheet

  var A = s_info.getRange('C11').getValue();  // Ticket
  var B = s_info.getRange('C3').getValue();   // Codigo CVM
  var C = s_info.getRange('C4').getValue();   // CNPJ
  var D = s_info.getRange('C5').getValue();   // Empresa
  var E = s_info.getRange('C6').getValue();   // Razão Social
  var F = s_info.getRange('C13').getValue();  // Tipo de Ação
  var G = s_info.getRange('C9').getValue();   // Listagem
  var H = s_info.getRange('C10').getValue();  // Atividade
  var I = s_info.getRange('C18').getValue();  // Setor
  var J = s_info.getRange('C19').getValue();  // Subsetor
  var K = s_info.getRange('C20').getValue();  // Segmento
  var L = s_info.getRange('C7').getValue();   // Situação Registro


  var S_Info = [];
  S_Info.push(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L);

  var ss_t = SpreadsheetApp.openById(target_Id);   // Target spreadsheet
  var t_relacao = ss_t.getSheetByName('Relação');  // Target sheet

  var lr = t_relacao.getLastRow();
  var lc = t_relacao.getLastColumn();

  var columnNumber = S_Info.length;

  var export_r = t_relacao.getRange(lr,1,1,columnNumber).setValues([S_Info]);

}
```

Comment: thanks, that is the answer i was looking for, only changed in last line to (2,1,lr,columnNumber), cos it was obviously overwriting 1st row, but that was my mistake to begin with

Comment: (lr+1,1,1,columnNumber) instead, duh

Answer (score 0):

This package converts excel-based coordinate to normal coordinates.

see: [ExcelCoordinates](https://github.com/AndoGhevian/ExcelCoordinates)

Comment: thanks but i dont think that it is really my problem, i know how offset works with google spreassheet https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379, what i dont know is how to take the data, make a string, array then setvalues the way i want